How can I do indirect database calls in a custom Wordpress plugin?
I am using Plugin Check(PCP) from the WordPress Performance Team and Plugin Review Team to check my custom plugin. I get the following warning message: "Use of a direct database call is discouraged." So I modified my post update to the following code:
$cache_key = 'add_guid_to_schedule';
$add_guid_to_schedule = wp_cache_get( $cache_key );
if( false === $add_guid_to_schedule ){
    $add_guid_to_schedule = $wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, array(
        'guid' => esc_url(site_url() . "?page_id=$new_id")
    ), array( 'id' => $new_id )
); 

    wp_cache_set( $cache_key, $add_guid_to_schedule );
}

I wrapped it with wp_cache_get() & wp_cache_set() expecting to satisfy the warning.
But Plugin Check(PCP) returns the same warning pointing to the update line:
$add_guid_to_schedule = $wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, array(

I think this is being triggered because you are updating a core table and there's a dedicated function for that: wp_update_post

As Chris Haas mentioned, You must consider using WordPress's built-in functions or APIs instead of directly interacting with the database. For updating posts, you can use wp_update_post() function, which handles post updates in a more WordPress-friendly way.
change these lines
$add_guid_to_schedule = $wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, array(
    'guid' => esc_url(site_url() . "?page_id=$new_id")
), array( 'id' => $new_id )

with
$post_data = array(
    'ID'   => $new_id,
    'guid' => esc_url( get_permalink( $new_id ) ),
);

$add_guid_to_schedule = wp_update_post( $post_data );

